# How to auto detect a user language in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a way to detect a user language?

In DAX, one may use `USERNAME()` to get the user name, is there anything equivalent (in DAX, M, or elsewhere) to get the user's language?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You could always maintain a mapping of users to languages and then lookup the USERNAME() in this table.

If you're looking for translations, this is a [feature available in SSAS Tabular](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/translations-in-tabular-models-analysis-services)